# Reproduce curl request in ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

I have next curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset: UTF-8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"destId":684}' https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?apiKey=VIATOR_API_KEY
```

This curl request is working correct. If I will try to move **apiKey** parameter to data hash, I'm getting an error that apiKey is missing. For example

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset: UTF-8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"destId":684, "apiKey":VIATOR_API_KEY}' https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products
```

I can't understand what is the difference between this two requests.

Obviously, instead of VIATOR_API_KEY I'm using real value.

And now I'm trying to reproduce this curl request in ruby.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

API_KEY        = ENV['VIATOR_API_KEY']
BASE_URL       = "http://viatorapi.viator.com/service"
path           = "/search/products"

# Full reference
uri = URI.parse "#{BASE_URL}#{path}?apiKey=#{API_KEY}"

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.initialize_http_header({"Content-type" => "application/json", "charset" => "UTF-8", "Cache-Control" => "no-cache"})
request.set_form_data('destId' => 684)

response = http.request(request)

puts response.body

if response.code == "200"
  # Do something
end
```

Now I'm getting 415 error **Unsupported Media Type**.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I've figured out what it has been due to.
Before setting data parameters `request.set_form_data('destId' => 684)`
request header is

```
{"content-type"=>["application/json"], "charset"=>["UTF-8"], "cache-control"=>["no-cache"]}
```

after

```
{"content-type"=>["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], "charset"=>["UTF-8"], "cache-control"=>["no-cache"]}
```

So, somehow it `set_form_data` changed content-type

Comment: That HTTP error happens when the Content-Type is incorrect. I would check that.

Comment: Are you JSON encoding your form data? I don't think Net::HTTP does that for you. `JSON.dump('destId' => 684)` instead.

Comment: [cURB](https://github.com/taf2/curb) is a good choice when trying to do curl-ish things in Ruby.

Comment: If your "UPDATE" is the solution to the problem, then please remove it from your question and create an answer, explaining why it was the solution. SO will allow you to select that answer which will close the question as "solved". This is important to the system and to those who use the site. Also, don't use "UPDATE" or "EDIT" type tags. Instead, include the information into the text as if it'd been there all along. SO has revision history if we need to see what's changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you can use the gem [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) is a curl wrapper is quite easy to translate curl request, here is the example for your request

```
require 'typhoeus'

request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products",
  method: :post,
  params: { apiKey: "VIATOR_API_KEY" },
  body: { destId: 684},
  headers: { 'Content-Type' => "application/json", charset: "UTF-8",'Cache-Control' => "no-cache" }
)

request.on_complete do |response|
  if response.success?
    # hell yeah
  elsif response.timed_out?
    # aw hell no
    log("got a time out")
  elsif response.code == 0
    # Could not get an http response, something's wrong.
   log(response.return_message)
  else
    # Received a non-successful http response.
    log("HTTP request failed: " + response.code.to_s)
  end
end

request.run

#curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset: UTF-8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"destId":684}' https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?apiKey=VIATOR_API_KEY
```

executing:

```
irb(main):112:0' => #<Typhoeus::Response:0x007fd46396b920 @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>0.933899, :starttransfer_time=>0.93374, :appconnect_time=>0.52442, :pretransfer_time=>0.5244530000000001, :connect_time=>0.25838099999999997, :namelookup_time=>0.000657, :redirect_time=>0.0, :effective_url=>"https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?apiKey=VIATOR_API_KEY", :primary_ip=>"54.165.220.73", :response_code=>200, :request_size=>269, :redirect_count=>0, :return_code=>:ok, :response_headers=>"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 17:24:23 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nContent-Length: 372\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\n\r\n", :response_body=>"{\"errorReference\":\"~21084218484370761736807418\",\"data\":null,\"dateStamp\":\"2016-04-28T10:24:23+0000\",\"errorType\":\"EXCEPTION\",\"errorMessage\":[\"API ACCESS DENIED!!! Api Key 'VIATOR_API_KEY' is invalid or missing\"],\"errorName\":\"Exception\",\"success\":false,\"totalCount\":1,\"vmid\":\"331004\",\"errorMessageText\":[\"API ACCESS DENIED!!! Api Key 'VIATOR_API_KEY' is invalid or missing\"]}", :debug_info=>#<Ethon::Easy::DebugInfo:0x007fd463988ca0 @messages=[]>}, @request=#<Typhoeus::Request:0x007fd464810f98 @base_url="https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products", @original_options={:method=>:post, :params=>{:apiKey=>"VIATOR_API_KEY"}, :body=>{:destId=>684}, :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", :charset=>"UTF-8", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}}, @options={:method=>:post, :params=>{:apiKey=>"VIATOR_API_KEY"}, :body=>{:destId=>684}, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", :charset=>"UTF-8", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}, :maxredirs=>50}, @response=#<Typhoeus::Response:0x007fd46396b920 ...>, @on_headers=[], @on_complete=[#<Proc:0x007fd464810e58@/Users/toni/learn/ruby/stackoverflow/scripting/typhoeus_request.rb:11>], @on_success=[]>, @handled_response=nil>
    irb(main):113:0>
```

a little bit pretty

```
irb(main):039:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):043:0> puts request.response.to_yaml
--- &3 !ruby/object:Typhoeus::Response
options:
  :httpauth_avail: 0
  :total_time: 0.6263529999999999
  :starttransfer_time: 0.6262380000000001
  :appconnect_time: 0.264124
  :pretransfer_time: 0.264161
  :connect_time: 0.131438
  :namelookup_time: 0.00059
  :redirect_time: 0.0
  :effective_url: https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?apiKey=VIATOR_API_KEY
  :primary_ip: 54.165.220.73
  :response_code: 200
  :request_size: 269
  :redirect_count: 0
  :return_code: :ok
  :response_headers: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 06:25:36 GMT\r\nContent-Type:
    application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nContent-Length: 371\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\n\r\n"
  :response_body: '{"errorReference":"~2155052986177618334013969","data":null,"dateStamp":"2016-04-28T23:25:36+0000","errorType":"EXCEPTION","errorMessage":["API
    ACCESS DENIED!!! Api Key ''VIATOR_API_KEY'' is invalid or missing"],"errorName":"Exception","success":false,"totalCount":1,"vmid":"331009","errorMessageText":["API
    ACCESS DENIED!!! Api Key ''VIATOR_API_KEY'' is invalid or missing"]}'
  :debug_info: !ruby/object:Ethon::Easy::DebugInfo
    messages: []
request: !ruby/object:Typhoeus::Request
  base_url: https://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products
  original_options:
    :method: :post
    :params: &1
      :apiKey: VIATOR_API_KEY
    :body: &2
      :destId: 684
    :headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      :charset: UTF-8
      Cache-Control: no-cache
  options:
    :method: :post
    :params: *1
    :body: *2
    :headers:
      User-Agent: Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus
      Content-Type: application/json
      :charset: UTF-8
      Cache-Control: no-cache
    :maxredirs: 50
  on_complete:
  - !ruby/object:Proc {}
  on_headers: []
  response: *3
  on_success: []
handled_response: 
=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you! Was going crazy with this one. My very basic GET request was working with a pure Curl command and Postman but no matter what Ruby library I tried I was getting an error. Until I tried Typhoeus

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the API documentation for that site, but it appears that the endpoint expects `apiKey` to be a url query parameter and *not* in the payload.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Api documentation said:
"The API key must be appended to every API call as a URL parameter for both GET and POST calls."

But, anyway, in ruby script I've send request with apiKey in URL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to pure Ruby and `Net::HTTP` then I recommend [`requests`](https://github.com/cyx/requests), a wrapper on `Net::HTTP` that makes it very easy to send requests.